# Why is finder asking to authenticate when copying to my external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, macos, external-disk, authentication, authorization

*macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (MacBook Air)*

I am trying to move a directory/folder from my local disk to an external hard drive. But I get an error that says:

> **Modifying "Remote Disk" requires an administrator name and password**
>
> To move "`<your-folder>`", click Authenticate.

But I do not see any button or link labeled <kbd>Authenticate</kbd>. Also, [I read here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3565554?tstart=0) there might be a solution involving right-clicking the destination drive then selecting <kbd>Get Info</kbd> button. However, there is nothing there I can click.

So how can I move this folder to my external drive?

#### Full screen capture movie .gif

[image]

[Click here to see the full screen capture movie .gif.](https://ibb.co/jihRKF)

#### Step 1.

Here is where I get the error message after attempting to move the folder.

[image]

#### Step 2.

The 'Get Info' window is no help.

[image]

Comment: That is not an external hard drive... it seems to be a remote DVD burner that was found on another mac... Try taking another look, check disk utility, see if you find your hard drive... please send us the result from ‘diskutil list’

Answer (score 2):

@bret7600 correctly pointed out in a comment that this is not an external hard drive. The external drive showed up in the Finder when I originally installed it but it went away after I clicked what I thought was a dropdown menu. I then proceeded under the assumption that the object that remained was what I was really looking for.

I had to reinstall the external drive by plugging it in to my USB. I could work on it successfully after reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but, if you can't seem to find the locked disk in Finder, you can use the Disk Utility program from the Applications > Utilities folder. The drive, once attached via USB, will be listed there, select it, and select "Mount". The password prompt will be triggered, enter the disk password and you should be set.